# Get content from pre element and run as javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I have a bunch of JavaScript snippets each contained in their own `pre` tags. I would like to know if it is possible to get the content out of the `pre` tag and run it as JavaScript.

For example let say one of my `pre` tags look like this:

```
<pre id="basic-alert">alert('Hello World');</pre>
```

When I click a button I want to get the content from within this `pre` and run it as JavaScript.

I know I can simply do this

```
$('[data-target="#basic-alert"]').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('Hello World');
});
```

But I have a quite a few code examples and would like to know if it is possible to avoid adding each of them into the JavaScript file. I would like to do something like this

```
<div class="code-example">
    <button>Run Code</button>
    <pre>alert('Hello World');</pre>
</div>
```

Then call something like this in JavaScript

```
$('.code-example > button').on('click', function(e) {
    var code = $(this).closest('.code-example').find('pre').text();
    executeJS(code);
});
```

`executeJS` is not a function I have made, I just used it because I am not sure what the code to would be to dynamically execute JavaScript code.

I do have access to `PHP` for any server side scripting. Not sure if that will make this task easier or not, but thought I would state it anyways. If this is impossible please just let me know.

Comment: I haven't tried any PHP solutions. How would I get eval to work on a dynamic call?

Comment: *You tried the javascript function eval?

Comment: Javascript has an eval function? How did I not know this?

Comment: wouldn't it just be easier to have a JS snippet `function basic_alert() { alert('hello world'); }`, which is "live" code, instead of storing your code as plaintext?

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh because you didn't try searching for it.

Comment: @Popnoodles I wish I had a good excuse, but I did some really bad google searchs before this should have search for `run plain text as javascript` I am sorry for this question.

Comment: @MarcB There is a bunch of examples. I think I counted well over 100. I was hoping to avoid writing a function for each example. Because that is what I have now actually.

Comment: how's writing a bunch of functions any different from writing a whole bunch of divs? at least with the functions you don't have to resort to eval()

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh your functions would be written at the same time as the HTML, you shouldn't need to do anything twice, or is this hard-coded HTML?

Comment: @MarcB These are hard coded in `HTML`. I have access to php but their is no database for the page to pull content from. So if I wrote out all of the js I would have to hard code it all into html.

Comment: @MarcB I know why it is bad to use `eval` in `php` and avoid it so but would using `eval` like below be that bad?

Comment: eval in any language is bad. at least in your case the code being evaluated is "obvious". But dynamically generating code-as-string then `eval()`ing it makes for VERY hard to debug/diagnose problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to change your code like this

```
$('.code-example > button').on('click', function(e) {
  var code = $(this).parent().find('pre').html();
  eval(code);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `executeJS()` with `eval()` and it should work as intended.

More information on [javascript eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: I wasn't aware that the answer required any code besides 'eval'. My answer clearly states "Replace executeJS with eval". Is there a community understanding I'm not aware of here?

Comment: Yours is basically the same as what mine was except the code words are formatted. The keyword is formatting, not code.

Comment: Yes it is basically the same and includes a reference to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
<pre id="basic-alert">alert('Hello World')</pre>
<button onclick="eval(document.getElementById('basic-alert').innerHTML);">Click Me!</button>
```

jQuery EDIT:

```
<pre id="basic-alert">alert('Hello World')</pre>
<button onclick='eval($("#basic-alert").text());'>Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: If you didn't notice OP is using jQuery. Inline JS in this instance is vulgar.